# How to generate a set of randomly generated abundances under the condition that they meet a specific level of evenness?

Tags: r

I want to generate 100 random numbers (meant to represent species abundance) under the condition that the numbers equal a given species evenness.

E.g., I want to create a 100x1 Matrix (M) of values wherein `-sum(p_i*log(p_i))/log(100) = 0.78`

Where, `p_i = M[i,1]/sum(M[,1])` and 0.78 is the desired species evenness.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Cool question. I'm following this one. A couple questions though: do all values need to be positive integers? Can any values be zero?

Comment: @Skaqqs Thanks! I asked this question because I think the strength of one of my thesis methods depends on species evenness. To answer your questions, yes, all of the values needs to be positive integers and greater than zero, because it is meant to represent a species abundance dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done something. I don't know if it will suit you. It is such a small monte-carlo.
But first, I have to start with the Shannon Index. There seems to be an error in your equation. I used this equation
[image]

Jet is my `H` function.

```
H = function(x) -sum(x/sum(x)/log(x/sum(x)))
```

I went on to create a slightly stretched, I admit, special sample function.

```
ssample = function(n, n10){
  if(sum(n10)>1) stop("sum n10>1")
  if(sum(n10<1)) n10=c(n10, 1-sum(n10))
  x = as.numeric()
  for(i in 1:length(n10)) {
    x = c(x, sample(1:(10^i), n*n10[i], replace = T))}
  x
}
```

If we want to find `H` equal to approximately 0.78, this function must receive a special weights parameter `n10`.

```
n=100
n10 = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.08, 0.05, 0.02)
```

It's straight ahead. We run monte-carlo for 10,000 iterations.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1111)
df = tibble(n1 = 1:10000) %>%
  mutate(x = map(n1, ~ssample(n, n10))) %>%
  mutate(H = map(x, ~H(.x))) %>%
  unnest(H)

df %>% filter(H>0.7799 & H<0.7801) %>%
  arrange(H)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
     n1 x               H
  <int> <list>      <dbl>
1  7550 <dbl [100]> 0.780
```

As you can see, one vector with `H` between `0.7799` and `0.7801` was drawn.
Let's see it on the plot.

```
fgat = function(x) tibble(n = x, gat = 1:length(x))
df %>% filter(H>0.7799 & H<0.7801) %>% 
  mutate(x = map(x, ~fgat(.x))) %>%
  unnest(x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(gat, n))+
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle(paste("Random species abundance with Shannon Index = 0.780"))+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')
```

[image]

Now let's check what our drawn vectors look like for the range `H> 0.779 & H <0.781`.

```
df %>% filter(H>0.779 & H<0.781) %>% arrange(H) %>% 
  mutate(H = H %>% round(4) %>%  paste() %>% fct_inorder()) %>%
  mutate(x = map(x, ~fgat(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gat, n, color=H))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(vars(H))+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')
```

[image]

Is it good enough for you?

**Update for @Skaqqs**

```
library(microbenchmark)

f = function(n, nmc, n10){
  df = tibble(n1 = 1:nmc) %>%
    mutate(x = map(n1, ~ssample(n, n10))) %>%
    mutate(H = map(x, ~H(.x))) %>%
    unnest(H)
}

ggplot2::autoplot(microbenchmark(f(100, 10000, n10), times=100))
```

[image]

**Update for @Dr_brachiopod**

I have to admit that finding a solution made me a bit tired. Ultimately, however, it turned out quite well. To answer your question, what is `n10`. It is a vector of "weights" which determines how many percent of draws will be in the range 1:10, how many 1:100, how many 1:1000 etc. See the chart below. That should clear everything up.

[image]

The graph shows the density of the distribution of randomly selected `H` values with the expected value of `H = 0.78` marked. As you can see, not all combinations of the `n10` are suitable for drawing this particular value.

When it comes to taking a sample with a certain `H` value, use a simple `filter`, e.g. like this `df %>% filter(H>0.779 and H<0.781)`.

Comment: How long does it take to find a suitable vector?

Comment: On my computer, it takes just over 1 second. See my answer update. Of course, it all depends also on how exactly you want to draw a sample that meets the assumption of equality of species. With less accuracy, the number of monte-carlo iterations can probably be lower, and the time itself is definitely shorter.